# Correct method for error propagation in pseudo-data approach using model

Tags: computational-physics, error-analysis, statistics

I want to compute the error on the integral over experimental data $(y_i,\delta y_i)$ in a pseudo-data approach using model ($x_i$ are assumed to be known error-less numbers).

If I were using direct data integration (trapezoidal rule) I would randomly generate many clones $j=1...N$ of the data

$$ (x_i,y_i^{[j]}), $$

each generated from distribution having $y_i$ as mean and $\delta y_i$ as the standard deviation (well, the standard pseudo-data approach) and so get the whole distribution of integrals $I^{[j]}$. Then I can compute the mean and the error:

$$ I_{mean} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N I^{[j]}, \quad I_{error} = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N (I_{mean}-I^{[j]})^2 }$$

Things become much less clear if I fit the model to the pseudo-data and compute integral from the model. The pseudo-data have no longer error bars on them, the error bars on "initial" data are actually there to indicate where the "true" data could lie (correct?). Pseudo-data are simulating many possible different realizations of the "true" data, and true data have no errors. So should I fit the model to the pseudo-data giving each point the same weight? This can lead to disaster: a point having initially large error can be, in pseudo-data placed very far. Giving this point the same weight as other have can completely spoil the fit (least-square is sensitive to outlier) ale lead to nonsense results (model has usually not enough freedom to accommodate all data). It seems far better to provide also the pseudo-data with original error bars (i.e. weights inversely proportional to their squares) but I see no theoretical justification for such approach. What is the meaning of pseudo-data with error bars? Such approach contradicts the standard pseudo-data error estimation procedure.

Question is simple: how to correctly do error propagation in pseudo-data approach using model to compute integral.

Comment: If you don't get an answer in a few days, you may want to try at [stats.se]

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?